# Returning From Suspend, Ubuntu 18.04 loses wired Internet connection

Tags: suspend

In Ubuntu 18.04 I can no longer return from "suspend" and have a wired Internet connection.  This was NOT true in previous versions of Ubuntu and its flavors.  In order to reestablish an wired Internet connection I have to now restart the system.  This is happening on a desktop system, not a laptop.  Unusual, and related to 18.04 changes.

Comment: What kernel version are you running and have you tried an upstream kernel? Also, what's your ethernet card? It'll be helpful to look to cross-reference your model with kernel changes. Basically, we want to figure out if this is an Ubuntu/DE thing or a kernel thing.

Comment: Kernel is 4.15.0-22-generic.  Ethernet card is "product RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller.  Hope that answers your question.  No issues with suspend and resume until I installed 18.04.  No system hardware changes were made.

Comment: Could you try grabbing a mainline kernel from the ppa? you'd need headers all, headers generic, linux image unsigned, and modules. Install with dpkg -i *.deb. Remember if you have any issue, you can use GRUB to go back to your old kernel. If that still doesn't work we can probably rule out a kernel bug and start looking at other things. This is an okay starting point because although it's unlikely, it's easy to test. http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: Sorry, that activity is unfamiliar to me.  I do know that since 18.04 every version of Ubuntu that I tried, Ubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE, Ubuntu-Budgie, and Xubuntu had the same problem, so it came with this latest version.    Sorry I cannot help more.

Comment: @Don43085, were you able to find a solution to this?